# Using ANT to comment out an XML tag in an external file

Tags: xml, ant, comments

I'm looking for the easiest way to use ANT to comment out an XML tag in an external XML file. XMLTask has an uncomment feature, but not comment, for some reason.

I could achieve this with replaceregexp or replace, but I would rather not as it seems like there should be a much easier way.

So for example, let's say I have file.xml:

```
<KeepMeTag someAttribute="something">
<SomeOtherTag someAttribute="something" />
```

...how could I, using ANT, comment out SomeOtherTag so that it looks something like:

```
<!-- <SomeOtherTag someAttribute="something" /> -->
```

Note that, the real tag actually itself has some regular expressions in it, and several other attributes, and is rather long. So, I would prefer a way to access the SomeOtherTag tag via XPath and just say "comment!"...if that is at all possible, rather than "replacing" occurrences of the particular string, as a) it is very long to add to my build, and b) likely to break the build if the XML changes slightly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [replaceregex task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html). That should be able to do the trick. To make it easier to use in multiple places you can wrap it in a [macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html).

It could look something like this. I haven't tested this though. Note that it does not take care of `>` written in attribute values

```
<macrodef name="outcomment">
  <attribute name="file">
  <attribute name="tagName">
  <sequential>
    <replaceregexp file="@{file}"
           match="(<@{tagname}[^>]/>)"
           replace="<!--\1 -->"
     />
  </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Note that regex have a hard time matching nested tags. If you only have other types of nested tags, you are be able to match the closing tag. It is impossible if you have nested tags with the same name.

If you want something more advanced consider [writing your own task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I did say this in the question "I could achieve this with replaceregexp or replace, but I would rather not as it seems like there should be a much easier way.". Even if I did want to use replaceregex, I don't know how to express this: "add <!-- before the match and --> after".

Comment: You can use groups, and refer to them with `\1`

Answer (score 1):

Using [Saxon-B 9.1.0.8](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/), you can have a pretty clean solution:

### source.xml

```
<root>
    <KeepMeTag someAttribute="something">
        <SomeOtherTag someAttribute="something" />
    </KeepMeTag>
</root>
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="ant-xslt-comment-out-element" default="run" basedir=".">
    <target name="run">
        <fail unless="out.dir"/>

        <xslt 
            style="transform.xsl"
            includes="source.xml"
            destdir="${out.dir}"
        >
            <factory name="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
            <identitymapper/>
        </xslt>
    </target>
</project>
```

### transform.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <!-- To serialize with saxon:serialize() -->
    <xsl:output name="default" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <!-- XSLT identity transformation -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SomeOtherTag">
        <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:value-of select="saxon:serialize(., 'default')" />
        </xsl:comment>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Ant command

```
ant -lib saxon9.jar
```

### Resulting XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <KeepMeTag someAttribute="something">
        <!--<SomeOtherTag someAttribute="something"/>-->
    </KeepMeTag>
</root>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just came across an alternative ant task during work called `xmltask`. To quote their own introduction:

> xmltask provides the facility for automatically editing XML files as part of an Ant build. Unlike the standard filter task provided with Ant, it is XML-sensitive, but doesn't require you to define XSLTs.

I have no experience with it, but take a look at the documentation: 
http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/

Comment: xmltask only has functionality to uncomment a tag, not to comment it.